# Why is this happening with base converter?

Tags: ruby

I am building a number base converter. Here is my code:

```
def num_to_s(num, base)
  results = []
  remainders = []
  while base <= num   
    result = num / base  #divide the initial value of num
    num = result         #put that back in num so you can do it again
    results << num       #push into array, then map for remainders
  end
  remainders << results.map{|i| result = i % base}    #get remainders (doesn't shovel first one?)
  first_remainder = num % base      #since the first remainder isn't getting recorded
  return (first_remainder.to_s + remainders.to_s).reverse
end

num_to_s(13346, 7)
```

The modulo that gathers the remainders from the results array is not picking up the remainder from the very first iteration of that array. I remedied the skip by giving the first modulo operation it's own separate variable, which may be a cheap hack but it works. Why is this happening? And is there a better way to fix it (without some complete overhaul)?

It needs to convert up to base 16. I am aware that this will not convert base 16 yet because of the letters involved, I'll figure that when I get to it. But I am open to suggestions on that as well.

Comment: You are aware of `13346.to_s(7) #=> "53624"`?

Comment: It was not clear that this is an exercise. I thought you were trying to implement a method that already exists.

Comment: @Stefan that got edited out. i am heavily edited. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first operation you do is to modulo number by base. That’s why the initial is not kept. So, the easiest way to keep it is just to put it into an array initially:

```
def num_to_s (num, base)
  results = [num]       # keep the initial 

  while base <= num 
    num /= base         # divide the initial value of num
    results << num      # push into array, then map for remainders
  end 

  # reverse an array and only then join it into string
  results.map {|i| i % base}.reverse.join
end

puts num_to_s(13346, 7)
#⇒ 53624
```

Comment: Thanks mudasobwa! I like the way you cleaned it up :) I didn't think to add a variable/parameter to an array...and now that I see that you did it, I realize I didn't need that second array because map modifies. I'm learning everyday ;) I'm curious as to why you put num /= base... I haven't seen /= before (divided by or equal to?) can you explain that a little?

Comment: @seinna `var ★= var2` is a shorthand for `var = var ★ var2` for `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and maybe some other operations. It’s like `a += 5` increases `a` by `5`, `num /= base` divides `num` by `base` and puts the result back into `num`.